# Override "action swipe"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem. I have an ionic and angular app and I need to override the "swipe back" action to take it to a particular view. I have this code:

```
this.navController.navigateBack([url]);
```

But I don't know where to put it, since I can't find a way to override that action.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by Swipe Back?

Comment: Swipe finger left to right

Comment: Read Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures